# Concatenate lists from df column

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3], 'tokens': [["anna","brings","work","life"], ["apples","bananas"], ["sun","trial","once"]]})
```

what I am trying to do is simply concatenate all the strings from lists in the column into a single list so that the resulting list looks like this:

```
result_list = ["anna","brings","work","life", "apples","bananas","sun","trial","once"]
```

I have tried to iterate over each row and then each element in a list:

```
result_list = [item for sublist in df.tokens for item in sublist]
```

but what I get is a list every single symbol of lists.
What am I missing?

Comment: Your solution works fine for me. It gives `['anna', 'brings', 'work', 'life', 'apples', 'bananas', 'sun', 'trial', 'once']`

Comment: @jpp Confirmed same.

Answer (score 3):

Use [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
import pandas as pd

from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'id': [1, 2, 3], 'tokens': [["anna", "brings", "work", "life"], ["apples", "bananas"], ["sun", "trial", "once"]]})

result = list(chain.from_iterable(df.tokens))
print(result)
```

Comment: wouldn't `list(chain.from_iterable(df.tokens))` do the job already?

Comment: @hochl Or just `[*chain(*df.tokens)]` since we are in Python3 and we are consuming the tokens instantly anyway, so we also do not need the lazy evaluation of `from_iterable`.

Answer (score 1):

```
your_list = []
for i in range (0, len(df)):
    for j in range (0, len(df['tokens'][i])):
       your_list.append(df['tokens'][i][j])
your_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested list comprehension.

```
>>> [x for sub in df['tokens'] for x in sub]                                
['anna', 'brings', 'work', 'life', 'apples', 'bananas', 'sun', 'trial', 'once']
```

edit: which is equivalent to your attempt, which I missed. What you did should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = []
[a.extend(i) for i in df.tokens]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
['anna', 'brings', 'work', 'life', 'apples', 'bananas', 'sun', 'trial', 'once']
```